# Calculating a mean inside a dataframe and keeping old index python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe, indexing

I have a problem in the code below

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame()
Fun1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B',
        'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
Fun2 = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3','4','4','4','1',
        '1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','4']
time = ['X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Z','Z','Z','Z','X',
        'X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Z','Z','Z','Z']
X = [1,5,3,3,4,3,1,5,3,3,4,3,4,1,1,5,4,3,4,1,5,4,3,4]
Y = [2,3,4,1,1,5,2,3,4,1,1,5,3,3,4,3,4,1,1,5,3,5,1,2]
df = df.assign(Fun1=Fun1,Fun2=Fun2,time=time,X=X,Y=Y)
df = df.set_index(['Fun1', 'Fun2'])

for (index, group) in df.groupby('Fun2'):

    dfx = group.groupby('time')['X','Y'].mean()
```

My dataframe `dfx` is being indexed by `time`, I need it to keep the old multiindex that it had before.

Is there a way to do the mean inside the dataframe and keep my old index?

Desired output

```
                        X    Y  time
Fun1    Fun2
A          1           x1   y1   X
B          1           x2   y2   X
A          2           x3   y3   Z
...
```

Being x1, y1 etc the mean or each multiindex

Comment: Your example is not runnable. Please take another look at it.

Comment: @coldspeed it's fixed now!

Comment: Can you show your desired output? Although I don't think it'll be possible.

Comment: I edited in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot retain the old `MultiIndex` for the result using your current code: it's meaningless, because you aggregate across levels.

You can, however, retain `Fun1` as long as you also group on `Fun1`:

```
df.reset_index()\
  .groupby(['Fun1', 'Fun2', 'time'])\
  .mean()\
  .reset_index(level=-1)

          time         X         Y
Fun1 Fun2                         
A    1       X  3.000000  3.000000
     2       X  3.000000  1.000000
     2       Y  2.666667  2.666667
     3       Y  5.000000  3.000000
     3       Z  3.000000  4.000000
     4       Z  3.333333  2.333333
B    1       X  2.500000  3.000000
     2       X  3.000000  3.500000
     2       Y  3.666667  2.000000
     3       Y  1.000000  5.000000
     3       Z  4.000000  3.000000
     4       Z  4.000000  2.000000
```

Comment: I used `df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values('Fun1'), df.time])['X', 'Y'].mean()` and it brought me a better result, not ideal but workable

Comment: @GabrielKochVasconcellos Are you sure you know what you want? If you are grouping on Fun2 and time, that means you are grouping _across_ Fun1's various values, so Fun1 no longer has any meaning in your result. Are you able to visualise this?

Comment: I'm! Fun1 is necessary in another part of the code! I can show you why, but I don't think it would help much

Comment: @GabrielKochVasconcellos Okay, unless you also group by Fun1, you cannot retain it. So, do you want to also group on Fun1?

Comment: Yes! Is that possible?